# Add an Address with Label to Send Coins Address Book via a RPC call

Tags: transactions, client, commerce

Doing some ecommerce stuff

Im not a c++ guy..I know in C# this is all doable

Does the client support or could it support a RPC call on an open port to add an Address & label pair with an Amount

i.e ComputerWorld Order (5 x 7970) Order# 3340 100.5 BTC

You could have an Do you want to allow confirmation yes/No

This would then allow a 1 step process for users top purchase goods online instead of copy paste etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a label to an address that is used to receive coins, you best use [Accounts](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Accounts_explained). Later you can fetch balances of individual Accounts and see which orders have enough confirmations.

If you want to add a label to an address you send your coins to, use "comment-to" field in [an RPC call](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list#Full_list) that creates the transaction.